# Show that $\lim_{\tau \to t}\int_\Omega \Phi(x-\xi, t-\tau)u(\xi,\tau)d\xi = u(x,t)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, fundamental-solution

If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a limited domain with a $C^1$ boundary, and $U_T = \{ (x,t) : x \in \Omega, 0 < t< T \}$, I have to show that

$\lim_{\tau \to t^-}\int_\Omega \Phi(x-\xi, t-\tau)u(\xi,\tau)d\xi = u(x,t)$

for all $u \in C(\bar{U}_T)$, where $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution of the heat equation:

$\Phi(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \exp\left({\dfrac{-\|x\|^2}{4t}}\right)$ if $t>0$ and $\Phi(x,t) = 0$ if $t \leq 0$

This is the last question of a problem with 2 questions and the other is only to prove that:

$\Phi_t(x-\xi, t-\tau) - \Delta_x\Phi(x-\xi, t-\tau) = 0$

and

$\Phi_\tau(x-\xi, t-\tau) + \Delta_\xi\Phi(x-\xi, t-\tau) = 0$

but I don't see if those equalities help or not. I tried everything. Someone help?

Comment: This (seems to me) could be write as a convolution of $\Phi$ and $u$, and using the property that $\Phi(x, t)$ is very centred at $(0, 0)$ as $t\to 0$, one can prove the equality (which is sometimes called approximation to identity). You may refer to the part indtroducing the heat kernel in Chapter 5 of  Stein's *Fourier Analysis*.

Comment: Thank u very much, I will try that.